# Getting a PHP maximum execution time error

Tags: php

I'm getting a PHP "Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded" error even though the max_execution_time and max_input_time settings in my php.ini are set to 180. I also tried to make my script use `set_time_limit(0);` and `ini_set('max_execution_time', 180);` and that's not helping. I've made sure the right php.ini file is being used, checked `phpinfo()` output, all the setting values are what I'd expect them to be. The line of code throwing the error is calling curl_exec(), so I also try to add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 180);` and no luck, still getting the same 60 second timeout error. Running out of ideas as to what other timeout setting could possibly be causing this. Environment is Windows with PHP running as FastCGI module.

Comment: Perhaps a basic question but, did you remember to restart your webserver after making the changes to the php.ini file?

Comment: After changing in the ini i hope you would have restarted the server... If not then plz restart n check. Writing set_time_limit(0) must have worked.

Comment: I did. As I said,  even checked in phpinfo() to make sure the values were reflected, and they were not without restarting the web server.

Comment: Does it work in the CLI version at least? Changed fpm.ini as well? Apache modules (e.g. mod_reqtimeout)? FastCGI [-*timeout](https://serverfault.com/questions/80929/disable-the-timeouts-on-apache-httpd-and-fastcgi) settings? What does `ini_get("max_…` yield at runtime? Tried a `.user.ini` to override?

Comment: @mario Thanks for getting me on the right track. I ran ini_get() precisely where the call was failing, and it wasn't yielding the value I was expecting. I searched a bit more and discovered that there was a piece of code elsewhere that was overriding it. Problem solved. Many thanks again. If you want to put in an answer along the lines of doing ini_get() where the call is failing and searching for other instances of ini_set() or set_time_limit() I will mark it as the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run ini_get() precisely where the call is failing and see if it yields the value expected. If not, searched your code for something overriding the value you're expecting.